# Connecting Kinect for Windows with PCL and OpenCV

Tags: opencv, kinect, point-cloud-library

My primary goal is to set up a basic c++ solution with Cmake, where I could use PCL's and OpenCV's features to manipulate the data acquired from the Kinect for Windows sensor.

I use:
- Kinect for Windows and also the SDK, because OpenNI isn't compatible with the new version of the Kinect. https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect would be one of the solutions, but It doesn't work with Windows 8 (according to the README file)

Then I thought, I'll use Cmake to generate VS solution and I've tried with this CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)
project(MultiKinect)
add_executable(pcl pcl.cpp)
include_directories("C:/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Kinect/v1.6/inc")
link_directories("C:/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Kinect/v1.6/lib/x86")
target_link_libraries(pcl "C:/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Kinect/v1.6/lib/x86/Kinect10.lib")
```

But I get the following compilation error:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_NuiGetSensorCount referenced in function main   
Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <NuiApi.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    int number;
    NuiGetSensorCount(&number);

    return (0);
}
```

In the future it would be easier to generate C++ solutions with Cmake, rather than set up the proper dirs under the project properties. What is the preferred way to create Visual Studio C++ solution for use with Kinect for Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Visual Studio 10 / Visual Studio 11 generator it works fine. I used Visual Studio 10 Win64 generator, that was the problem.